# In which types exit property e.changedTouches? (React + TypeScript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want fix all errors
I have this error 1
[image: error]

And this error 2
[image: error 2]

My code

```
function onMouseTouchDown(e: React.SyntheticEvent<HTMLDivElement>) {
    e.preventDefault()
    setDown(true)

    if (e.type === "touchmove" && e.changedTouches) {
      setX(e.changedTouches[0].pageX - e.currentTarget.offsetLeft)
    } else {
      setX(e.pageX - e.currentTarget.offsetLeft)
    }

    setScrollLeft(e.currentTarget.scrollLeft)
  }
```

codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/slider-jc-consoleerror-type-error-tktvxn?file=%2Fsrc%2Fhooks%2FuseSlider.ts%3A49%2C6

Help me please fix this error

Comment: Some good readinging perhaps https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/125981 and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you give some advices how improve this question? - should I delete images?

Comment: 1. Post error messages as text not images.  2. Include all code in play IN the question not as a link elsewhere.  3. Reduce to smallest code that reproduces the issue.  Sometimes just doing those things helps fix the issue for yourself. Also if you can, make it a snippet https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/how-do-i-create-a-react-stack-snippet-with-jsx-support

Comment: Any reason for 1?
AI can't recognize text on image for somebody who will google this question?

Comment: its hard to post react code here ctrl+c ctrl+v doesn't work - that's reason why I attach codesandbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To search in which property exist some type go to developer.mozilla.org and search
[image]

[image]
And include it to your interface
[image]

If you need you can extend some type to your interface e.g TouchEvent